# Error when running Mautic as Azure App for Container with Azure Storage mount

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, mautic

I am trying to run Mautic as an Azure App for Container and have enabled WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE to use Azure Storage. I have followed the steps mentioned here https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/55046  to configure Azure Storage mount with a file share in the Docker container.

However, I am encountering an error during startup with the message Mautic not found in /var/www/html - copying now....

I have verified that the files are successfully copied to the Azure File Storage, but the error persists.

[image]

Below is my docker-compose.yml configuration:

```
version: "3"

services:
  mautic:
    image: mautic/mautic:v4-apache
    volumes:
      - mouticdatamount:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - MAUTIC_DB_HOST=mydb.mysql.database.azure.com
      - MAUTIC_DB_USER=mydbuser
      - MAUTIC_DB_PASSWORD=mydbpassword
      - MAUTIC_DB_NAME=mydbname
    restart: always
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
2023-07-15T07:20:25.335Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 9560:80 --name myhost_mautic_0_3cb64f5a -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=true -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=myhost -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=hostname.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=7e65b7bfda61c0327cd6b05b68172e68b22e90752de61b8d5f6484746acfcd5d -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=False mautic/mautic:v4-apache  

2023-07-15T07:24:16.260Z ERROR - multi-container unit was not started successfully
2023-07-15T07:24:16.261Z INFO  - Container logs from myhost_mautic_0_3cb64f5a = 2023-07-15T07:20:25.831636447Z Mautic not found in /var/www/html - copying now...

2023-07-15T07:24:21.707Z INFO  - Stopping site myhost because it failed during startup.
2023-07-15T07:30:33.880Z INFO  - Starting multi-container app..
```

Answer (score 0):

I get it working after trying out several things.

I updated the mount path to final folder instead of whole path. I am not sure if this helped solve it. So final mount is like this. Previously it was /var/www/html

[image]

Also, I updated the Azure setting for container WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT to 1800.

And finally, it took almost 18-20 min to get everything ready. I believe this was due to the time out which was caused by docker while copying the required files during running mautic container.

Comment: Krunal can you share any documentation you used as guidance to setup Mautic in Azure?  Wondering if we can use Azure App Service.

Comment: @EricHalsey I have tried with container on Azure App Service - which doesn't work well for Mautic as it introduces 30-40 second lag the moment you enable data persistence and I wasted almost 40 days working with Azure support to resolve this, they finally asked me to stop using it and asked to use VM directly to host container.